# ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion in React native Project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

In my react native project(0.63)when am trying to archive using xcode it is always getting failed.The error is:

```
  ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when i'm trying to archive using device it is working but when i select "Any ios device(arm64,armv) then the build failed with this error.

in my pod file i have:

```
 pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
```

I am running .xcworkspace project.

How should i reslove this issue?Any ideas?